# Unable to track free calls for printf

Tags: c, linux, printf, malloc, free

I'm writing are small memory profiler which is using the LD_PRELOAD trick. Overall it works good for malloc and free. Unfortunately I'm not able to track IO-Operations such as printf. Those functions get tracked correctly at the malloc functions but it didn't seam that they got passed to free. Here are code snippets:

```c
void heaptracker_init(void) 
{
    ignore = false;

    // get original symbols
    libc_hooks.malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    check_error_dlfcn(libc_hooks.malloc);

    // for the other primitives as well ...

    // init list for storing information
    if ((alloc_list = list_init()) == NULL)
        return;
    
// does write results from list
    if (atexit(heaptracker_destroy))
        return;

    initialized = true;
    
    stopped = true;

    // for concurrent access on list ...
    if ((errno = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL)) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    stopped = false;
}
```

The malloc routine does store the allocations in a list and performs the actual allocation.

```c
void *malloc(size_t size) 
{
   if (!initialized)
        heaptracker_init();

    void * (*libc_malloc)(size_t) = libc_hooks.malloc;

    void *p = libc_malloc(size);

    list_append(alloc_list, infos, p, size, stacktrace_length);
    return p;
}
```

The free routine looks like this:

```c
void free(void *ptr)
{

if (!initialized)
        heaptracker_init();


    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) != 0) 
        return;

    // does remove
    list_remove(alloc_list, ptr);    
    
    errno = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    libc_hooks.free(ptr);
}
```

For a small test programm like this one:

```c
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    char *buffer = malloc(100);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output should be:

```json
{
"type": "leak",
"bytes": 100,
"stacktrace": ["main"]
}
```

While the actual output is:

```json
[
   {
    "type": "leak",
    "bytes": 100,
    "stacktrace": ["main"]
    },
    {
     "type": "leak",
     "bytes": 1024,
     "stacktrace": ["main", "_IO_printf", ...,  "_IO_file_doallocate"]
     }
]
```

Comment: Probably a "leak" due to the buffer for stdout. Try printing to a file you explicitly open and close.

Comment: You're right thank you this doesn't happen if i open and close a file explicitly. I have another question if use some existing tools like valgrind this leak doesn't happen how can this occur? I know valgrind uses some other technique for tracking allocations. Is it possible to stick with my approach without getting these annoying messages from IO operations?

Comment: Valgrind does some filtering (look at the source and docs for "suppression files"). I don't know if that's the only technique they use.